# Minecraft flame arrows

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know you can make fire arrows by enchanting your bow or shooting the arrows through lava, but is there anyway you can light an individual arrow on fire and THEN shoot it? Without enchanting the bow.

Answer (score 8):

I'm sorry to tell you this, but no. There is not a way to light an arrow individually in vanilla minecraft without shooting it through lava or having an enchanted bow with Flame 1.